# winapi - non-sense file timestamps?

Tags: winapi, file, timestamp

I can't seem to get a reliable timestamp using winapi functions. For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
HANDLE file;
BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION finfo;
SYSTEMTIME systime;

file = CreateFile("test.txt",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
GetFileInformationByHandle(file,&finfo);
FileTimeToSystemTime(&finfo.ftLastWriteTime, &systime);
printf("  %s   %02d:%02d:%02d %d/%d/%d\n", "test.txt",  systime.wHour,systime.wMinute,systime.wSecond,systime.wDay,systime.wMonth,systime.wYear);
}
```

gives non-sense on all my files like:

```
test.txt   00:03:30 33/5/3
```

wDay seems to have values outside of range 1-31 and the times and dates are totally wrong. All other values in the BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION like name and size are correct, and in I full code I check for errors from all functions, but they all return passed. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your use of `filesize.QuadPart`. Try removing that from both the format string and the argument list, and see if it works.

If that helps, then look up the correct format string to use for a 64-bit quantity in `printf()`.

Comment: sorry i tried to cut down to only relavent code, there is nothing wrong with that part, 
LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
filesize.LowPart = finfo.nFileSizeLow;
filesize.HighPart = finfo.nFileSizeHigh;

The filesize gets reported correctly.

Comment: Okay, please try changing filesize.QuadPart to filesize.LowPart in your printf statement and see if that helps.

Comment: Replace %lld with %d if you switch to filesize.LowPart.

Comment: @Michael: %lld does not indicate a 64 bit quantity in the MS implementation of printf. I believe that is the root cause of the original problem.

Comment: Thanks in my compiler i had to use %I64u instead of %llu.